# Hibernate cannot find Entity Constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an other hibernate issue.
I am trying to receive all projects, which have the most recent messages. For that I try to get all messages, group them by their project id and apply the max function on the updated column.
My query is build as shown here:

```
query.select(from).orderBy(builder.desc(from.get(Message_.UPDATED))).multiselect(from.get(Message_.ID),builder.max(from.get(Message_.UPDATED))).groupBy(from.get(Message_.PROJECT));
```

But I receive an Exception,

```
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: de.ls5.wt2.Message]
```

where it cannot transform the Result back into a Message Entity. Do I have to define a proper constructor? That would be very unfortunate, because it contains other entities, making the query very hard. And joining all messages with jointype right with above query doesnt work, sicne jointype right is not supported. Any advice how I can get a List of Message entities which have the id of the result of above query?

Any help is apreciated.

EDIT: Message class:

```
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;
    @OneToOne
    private User creator;
    @OneToOne
    private Project project;
    private String content;

    public Message() {

    }
    //getter and setter
   }
```

Comment: Well? You didn't show your `Message` class.

Comment: added the class, but I do not see how it is relevant, since hibernate normaly is able to transform it into a Message without a for this query specific contstructor.

Comment: do you have empty c'tor on `User` and `Project` classes as well? all fields have setters?

Comment: yes I do and their JAX-RS endpoints work just fine. It is just this specific query that does not work. Most likely because the max function is still an aggregation, hence influencing the signature of the result and making it hard to parse back (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are multiselecting only these two columns:

```
.multiselect(
    from.get(Message_.ID),
    builder.max(from.get(Message_.UPDATED))
)
```

You need to have a constructor for your query result made of two things:

- Object for Message_.ID (long id)
- Object for Message_.UPDATED (Date updated)

So, either create a custom object containing these fields with all args constructor. This is also called projection. Another and simpler way is to just create a constructor in the existing entity with these two parameters.

```
public Message(long id, Date updated) {
     this.id = id;
     this.updated = updated;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I used the createTupleQuery which basicly does what you described. Do you know by any chance how I can make my querry to apply the distinct clause on only a single attribute? edit: but i still need the other attribute.

Comment: dammit that does not help me. Using JAX-RS to code a webapplication and all i have it an entityManager that does not provide me a criteria which uses those things. But I read about the "having" clause. Do you know by any chance a function that allows me to define that i want to "groupby project having greatest(from.get("updated"))"? The greatest function does not work for paths (errror during compile time). Kinda afraid to open an other question for this

Comment: Creating a new question would work better because others would be able to find our solution as well. However, you can definitely use having clause and imo it is something you are looking for if you want to get the freshest (most recently updated) message